# Upper bounds on the permanent of dense 0-1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

I am looking for some result useful in deriving following (conjecture?):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $0-1$ entries.
Suppose, that exactly $k\leqslant n$ entries are equal to $0$.
Then $\mathrm{Per} A \leqslant n!\left(1-\frac{k}{2n}\right)$

Unfortunately, trying to derive this inequality from other estimates fails in general. For example, the inequality given in

> Adam G. Weyhaupt, *A note on some upper bounds for permanents of (0,1)-matrices*, Journal of Interdisciplinary Mathematics  **12** no 1 (2009) pp 123–128, doi:[10.1080/09720502.2009.10700615](https://doi.org/10.1080/09720502.2009.10700615) ([pdf](http://www.siue.edu/~aweyhau/research/papers/sdrbounds.pdf))

failed with $k=4$.

Comment: I should have naively guessed the upper bound $n!(1-k/n)$. Can you explain why the factor $1-\frac{k}{2n}$ is relevant?

Comment: The identity matrix $2\times 2$ with $k=2$ gives the equality $\mathrm{Per} I = 1 = 2!\left(1-\frac{2}{2\cdot 2}\right)$.

Comment: of course! I went to fast.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact, the maximum is achieved when no two of the 0's are in the
same row or column, giving the maximum value
  $$ S=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i {k\choose i}(n-i)!. $$
*Proof.* Suppose that there are two 0's in the same row, say the
first. Then some row, say the second, has all 1's. Expand the
permanent by the first two rows. One of the $2\times 2$ submatrices is
$\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&1\cr}$. Changing
this to $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}$
does not decrease any of the $2\times 2$ submatrices from the first
two rows, so the permanent of the entire matrix does not decrease. We
can iterate this procedure (possibly using columns instead of rows)
until no two 0's are in the same row and column, so the proof follows.

We now need to show that $S$ is at most $n!\left(
1 -\frac{k}{2n}\right)$. This is trivial for $k=1$, so assume $k>1$. 
By the Bonferroni inequalities
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_inequality), $S$ is
bounded by the first three terms, i.e.,
   $$ S\leq n!-k(n-1)!+{k\choose 2}(n-2)! =
          n!\left(1-\frac kn+\frac{{k\choose 2}}{n(n-1)}\right). $$
Since $k\leq n$ we have 
   $$ \frac{{k\choose 2}}{n(n-1)}\leq \frac{k}{2n}, $$
and the result follows.

Comment: \pmatrix{0&0\cr1&1\cr} gives $\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&1\cr}$ when you put a dollar sign at each end of it. 

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. By the way, I have checked, that solutions of more general extremal problems, using exactly the same ideas (changing a row or column that contains more than one zero) one can found in the paper [Maximum permanents of matrices of zeros and ones](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B6WHS-4D7CYGG-DM/2/d6f318c578b8d1102b7ff9862ffaa44b)